how to use constexpr to make constant std::array of pairs of char in C++?
this is my code trying to use constexpr to make constant std::array of pairs of char in c++, also any other info to make my code better is appriciated:
#pragma once
#include <array>

constexpr unsigned int deck_size = 52;
constexpr std::array<char, 4> suits{'H', 'D', 'C', 'S'};
constexpr std::array<char, 13> ranks{'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'};
typedef std::pair<char, char> card;
typedef std::array<card, deck_size> deck;

constexpr deck initialize_cards()
{
    deck cards;
    //deck cards{};
    int card_index = 0;
    for (auto const &suit : suits)
    {
        for (auto const &rank : ranks)
        {
            cards[card_index] = {rank, suit};
            // cards[card_index] = card{rank, suit};
            ++card_index;
        }
    }

    return cards;
}
constexpr deck cards = initialize_cards();

it gives me following error:
nemexia@NemminT:~/Desktop/Programming/projects/poker-probs$ g++ -O3 -s -DNDEBUG -Wall -march=native *.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:2:
models.hpp:26:40:   in ‘constexpr’ expansion of ‘initialize_cards()’
models.hpp:18:44: error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>& std::pair<_T1, _T2>::operator=(std::__conditional_t<std::__and_<std::is_move_assignable<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_T2> >::value, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&, std::__nonesuch&&>) [with _T1 = char; _T2 = char; std::__conditional_t<std::__and_<std::is_move_assignable<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_T2> >::value, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&, std::__nonesuch&&> = std::pair<char, char>&&]’
   18 |             cards[card_index] = {rank, suit};
      |                                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/string:51,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/ios:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/iostream:41,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_pair.h:737:7: note: ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>& std::pair<_T1, _T2>::operator=(std::__conditional_t<std::__and_<std::is_move_assignable<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_T2> >::value, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&, std::__nonesuch&&>) [with _T1 = char; _T2 = char; std::__conditional_t<std::__and_<std::is_move_assignable<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_T2> >::value, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&, std::__nonesuch&&> = std::pair<char, char>&&]’ declared here
  737 |       operator=(__conditional_t<__and_<is_move_assignable<_T1>,
      |       ^~~~~~~~
In file included from models.cpp:1:
models.hpp:26:40:   in ‘constexpr’ expansion of ‘initialize_cards()’
models.hpp:18:44: error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>& std::pair<_T1, _T2>::operator=(std::__conditional_t<std::__and_<std::is_move_assignable<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_T2> >::value, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&, std::__nonesuch&&>) [with _T1 = char; _T2 = char; std::__conditional_t<std::__and_<std::is_move_assignable<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_T2> >::value, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&, std::__nonesuch&&> = std::pair<char, char>&&]’
   18 |             cards[card_index] = {rank, suit};
      |                                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/array:43,
                 from models.hpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_pair.h:737:7: note: ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>& std::pair<_T1, _T2>::operator=(std::__conditional_t<std::__and_<std::is_move_assignable<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_T2> >::value, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&, std::__nonesuch&&>) [with _T1 = char; _T2 = char; std::__conditional_t<std::__and_<std::is_move_assignable<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_T2> >::value, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&, std::__nonesuch&&> = std::pair<char, char>&&]’ declared here
  737 |       operator=(__conditional_t<__and_<is_move_assignable<_T1>,
      |       ^~~~~~~~
nemexia@NemminT:~/Desktop/Programming/projects/poker-probs$ g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -s -DNDEBUG -Wall -march=native *.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:2:
models.hpp: In function ‘constexpr deck initialize_cards()’:
models.hpp:14:29: warning: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::value_type* std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::begin() const [with _Tp = char; long unsigned int _Nm = 4; const_iterator = const char*]’ [-Winvalid-constexpr]
   14 |     for (auto const &suit : suits)
      |                             ^~~~~
In file included from models.hpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/13/array:131:7: note: ‘const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::value_type* std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::begin() const [with _Tp = char; long unsigned int _Nm = 4; const_iterator = const char*]’ declared here
  131 |       begin() const noexcept
      |       ^~~~~
models.hpp: At global scope:
models.hpp:26:40: error: ‘constexpr deck initialize_cards()’ called in a constant expression
   26 | constexpr deck cards = initialize_cards();
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
models.hpp:10:16: note: ‘constexpr deck initialize_cards()’ declared here
   10 | constexpr deck initialize_cards()
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from models.cpp:1:
models.hpp: In function ‘constexpr deck initialize_cards()’:
models.hpp:14:29: warning: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::value_type* std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::begin() const [with _Tp = char; long unsigned int _Nm = 4; const_iterator = const char*]’ [-Winvalid-constexpr]
   14 |     for (auto const &suit : suits)
      |                             ^~~~~
In file included from models.hpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/13/array:131:7: note: ‘const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::value_type* std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::begin() const [with _Tp = char; long unsigned int _Nm = 4; const_iterator = const char*]’ declared here
  131 |       begin() const noexcept
      |       ^~~~~
models.hpp: At global scope:
models.hpp:26:40: error: ‘constexpr deck initialize_cards()’ called in a constant expression
   26 | constexpr deck cards = initialize_cards();
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
models.hpp:10:16: note: ‘constexpr deck initialize_cards()’ declared here
   10 | constexpr deck initialize_cards()
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
nemexia@NemminT:~/Desktop/Programming/projects/poker-probs$ g++ -O3 -s -DNDEBUG -Wall -march=native *.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:2:
models.hpp:26:40:   in ‘constexpr’ expansion of ‘initialize_cards()’
nemexia@NemminT:~/Desktop/Programming/projects/poker-probs$ g++ -O3 -s -DNDEBUG -Wall -march=native *.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:2:
models.hpp:26:40:   in ‘constexpr’ expansion of ‘initialize_cards()’
nemexia@NemminT:~/Desktop/Programming/projects/poker-probs$ g++ -O3 -s -DNDEBUG -Wall -march=native *.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:2:
models.hpp:26:40:   in ‘constexpr’ expansion of ‘initialize_cards()’
models.hpp:18:44: error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>& std::pair<_T1, _T2>::operator=(std::__conditional_t<std::__and_<std::is_move_assignable<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_T2> >::value, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&, std::__nonesuch&&>) [with _T1 = char; _T2 = char; std::__conditional_t<std::__and_<std::is_move_assignable<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_T2> >::value, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&, std::__nonesuch&&> = std::pair<char, char>&&]’
   18 |             cards[card_index] = {rank, suit};
      |                                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/string:51,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/ios:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/iostream:41,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_pair.h:737:7: note: ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>& std::pair<_T1, _T2>::operator=(std::__conditional_t<std::__and_<std::is_move_assignable<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_T2> >::value, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&, std::__nonesuch&&>) [with _T1 = char; _T2 = char; std::__conditional_t<std::__and_<std::is_move_assignable<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_T2> >::value, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&, std::__nonesuch&&> = std::pair<char, char>&&]’ declared here
  737 |       operator=(__conditional_t<__and_<is_move_assignable<_T1>,
      |       ^~~~~~~~
In file included from models.cpp:1:
models.hpp:26:40:   in ‘constexpr’ expansion of ‘initialize_cards()’
models.hpp:18:44: error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>& std::pair<_T1, _T2>::operator=(std::__conditional_t<std::__and_<std::is_move_assignable<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_T2> >::value, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&, std::__nonesuch&&>) [with _T1 = char; _T2 = char; std::__conditional_t<std::__and_<std::is_move_assignable<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_T2> >::value, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&, std::__nonesuch&&> = std::pair<char, char>&&]’
   18 |             cards[card_index] = {rank, suit};
      |                                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/array:43,
                 from models.hpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_pair.h:737:7: note: ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>& std::pair<_T1, _T2>::operator=(std::__conditional_t<std::__and_<std::is_move_assignable<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_T2> >::value, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&, std::__nonesuch&&>) [with _T1 = char; _T2 = char; std::__conditional_t<std::__and_<std::is_move_assignable<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_T2> >::value, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&, std::__nonesuch&&> = std::pair<char, char>&&]’ declared here
  737 |       operator=(__conditional_t<__and_<is_move_assignable<_T1>,
      |       ^~~~~~~~
nemexia@NemminT:~/Desktop/Programming/projects/poker-probs$ 

this is the error i get with the following build command:
g++ -O3 -s -DNDEBUG -Wall -march=native **.cpp
seems like its okay with c++20 but i want to know how to do similiar thing with c++11/14...

Can you post the formatted error message as a code, not a quote?

can't repro: https://godbolt.org/z/j9KMMKGao are you sure you are using proper build flags? Or maybe your compiler s to old.

Side note, do not use std::pair for things you can easily create your own struct with two members. (std::pair's main use is for template programming). With std::pair you force yourself and others to keep looking up what first and second actually mean, Also use using instead of typedef

you are missing #include <utility> for std::pair

fwiw, I can reproduce with msvc https://godbolt.org/z/j55qs6h9n

Looks like issue is you are building with wrong C++ standard: https://godbolt.org/z/EMcTesco3 I see this error with C++17 it is fine with C++20.

and it compiles with msvc when c++20 is enabled https://godbolt.org/z/YsfGqnacv

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator%3D

Please [edit] your question to clearly state you want to port C++20 code to specific older C++ standard. Start by improving title.

@MarekR the thing is i dont know if this is accepted way in C++20, i want to know if this is good for C++20 and how to modify it to become accepted for older standards

All major compilers agree this is fine in C++20, documentation clearly states difference between C++17/20, so I do not understand your problem.

@Nemexia The operator= for std::pair is not constexpr until C++ 20.  That seems to be the root cause of the compilation issue, and why it works only for C++20 and higher.

@Nemexia Why not simply write your own home-made pair class with a constexpr operator=?

@PaulMcKenzie: I would even say a dedicated class Card ;-)

For C++11, it would be more tricky, as rules in constexpr function are very strict (no for-loop).

@Jarod42 Yes, it seems this issue is totally avoidable if a Card class was created that had all the constexpr stuff in it instead of a raw std::pair being used (I am assuming anything above C++11).

For C++11, the simpler would be return {{'2', 'H'}, {'3', 'H'}, .., {'A', 'S'}};.

@Nemexia, I was suspecting pair::pair for constexpr. You just nailed it; the assignment operator is the cause.

For C++20 nerds: std::ranges::copy(std::views::iota(0,dec_size) | std::views::transform([](auto i){ return card{ranks[i%13], suits[i/13]};}), begin(cards)); instead of magic 13 use size(ranks). And define auto constexpr dec_size = size(ranks) * size(suits);, for good measure.
